# Device access APIs in Windows 9x

Tags: windows-98, windows

What were the programming interfaces used to access "raw" devices on Windows 95~ME? Specifically GPUs, but I'm also curious about other device types in general.

For example, on modern Linux (after the era of direct userspace PCI access, ugh), `/dev/dri/card0` is the device node through all GPU access is done (mainly via ioctl and mmap file operations). On Windows NT, I believe it would be `\\.\Display0` or something similar to that in the NT device namespace.

What did e.g. 3D-accelerated games in Windows 98 use to achieve the same thing? Were there DOS-style device names akin to `COM1:` for graphics cards, or NT-ish device names, or some other OS-provided interface, or did such programs mostly bypass the kernel entirely (i.e. having userspace DLLs directly poke at I/O ports)?

(Specifically, I'm curious about the layer *below* "programmer uses Direct3D functions", i.e. about what d3d*.dll itself or its equivalents would have used under the hood.)

Comment: A bit broad, isn't it.  Short Version: Windows has no user accessible drivers (VxD/WDM). DirectX **is** the low level API provided to access functionality. It already bypasses the GDI parts, giving a short/fast path to hardware. It is the equivalent of GPU drivers in Linux. Also, GPUs are a later development than Direc3D (and WinG). It's about giving a 3D pipeline way before 3D accelerators became GPUs.

Comment: Depends on the device, I think. I don’t know about graphics drivers, but I know raw block device access is performed by opening a handle to VWIN32.VXD and calling `DeviceIoControl` to invoke an interrupt handler at the DOS layer (!). Yes, really, even when there is no real-mode mapper active. This is the official guidance found in MSDN. I would imagine DirectX does something similar: open a handle to a VXD and invoke some ioctls.

Comment: if you are asking about Win95, Glide was common, as was necessary for the 3dfx voodoo cards. D3D came later. WinNT supported openGl, no D3D or Glide. Glide is of course a 3dfx manufacturer specific api

Comment: I can confirm using ioctl for accessing a floppy drive at the sector level in Win9x.

Comment: If someone knew a tool like strace on Linux it would perhaps be possible to identify how a program communicates with the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The low-level Win32 userspace device access API in Windows 9x is actually not all that different from the one in Windows NT: given a path pointing to a device node (which starts with `\\.\`), you can open a handle to the driver and use it to perform calls like [`DeviceIoControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol).  The catch is mostly in what devices are actually available.

For example, where in Windows NT one would open a block device node like `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` or `\\.\C:` to perform raw disk I/O, to do the same in Windows 9x one would instead open a handle to `\\.\VWIN32`, which is to say, to the VWin32 virtual device driver, and use that handle to perform a `DeviceIoControl` call, which in turn invokes… a software interrupt call one would find familiar from DOS programming.  Yes, this was the official way to do it, even with only 32-bit drivers in use.  This is described in KB articles like [Q125712](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/125712), [Q163920](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/163920) and in MSDN documentation.  (Not the contemporary online version, of course, but you should be able to dig it out from the CHM files on a MSDN CD from the period.)  Several other VxDs allow obtaining a handle to themselves in this way in order to invoke driver functions, although VWIN32 ioctls are the only ones I could find any documentation for.  Windows NT, of course, has no VxDs.

But some devices were shared between the two families.  In particular, display device nodes like `\\.\Display1` appear both in Windows 9x and NT, and Win32 calls like [`EnumDisplayDevices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaydevicesa) will return them.  Likewise COM and LPT communication ports.

How exactly DirectX specifically ends up using those APIs, I cannot say, but it seems at least some driver traffic does end up going through VxD entry points like `\\.\DDRAW.VXD` and `\\.\DSOUND.VXD`.  You can see for yourself by analysing DirectX 6 binaries bundled with Windows 98 SE.

16-bit programs could also use device access APIs inherited from Windows 3.x Enhanced mode, with which Windows 9x remained fully compatible; APIs like [interrupt 0x2f service 0x1684](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/windows/2f1684.html).  [KERNEL32 even provided undocumented, ordinal-only exports](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/kernel32/history/ords40.htm) allowing to directly perform `VxDCall` invocations from user space, that were normally available only to VxD drivers themselves.  But NT-style `\\.\` device paths were indubitably the intended, official API for Win32 applications.

Comment: Thanks – so I guess this whole concept was "down-ported" from NT3.x, in a sense.

Comment: @grawity Which is quite expected because Win32 API as such first originated on NT 3.x

Please note, though, that the device path (think IOCTL)-style `\\.\Display1` interface serves a very limited purpose when it comes to graphics and rendering. As I mentioned in my reply below, it was done through other, dedicated APIs.

Comment: I wrote this with the assumption that graphics rendering was only mentioned as an example, and not as a specific area of interest. But yes, this is worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 4):

For 3D rendering specifically, Windows display drivers expose a so called Direct3D Device Driver Interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/direct3d). DDI did exist at least for Windows 98, and quite likely on Windows 95 as well.

Comment: There must be an equivalent interface for OpenGL. For example the game 4x4 evo already supported OpenGL.

Comment: @zomega Yes, there is, and it's called ICD (installable client driver): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/loading-an-opengl-installable-client-driver